# how to join tables with NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

I've 2 `NSManagedObjects` Events and *PrivateEvents*, Where PrivateEvents is the subset of the Events. I just want to show only those Events which are not present in *PrivateEvents*, in a `UITableView`.

Please let me know who it can be done.

Comment: There are no "Table" in coreData, and there is no JOIN. You have only relations and entities. Ready Apple documentation pages first to understand that it is not traditional database.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a single kind of entity `Event` with a flag `isPivate`? This way you could get them with a single fetch request. If you use 2 separate entities, I believe you will have to do the filtering in code, you cannot do a `JOIN` on the entities.

Comment: -1 please dont 'further' this thinking in tables. As Grzegorz said as well : CD has no tables

Comment: +1 your idea of having only one MOM with a flag isPrivate sounds good to me though